# Работа сервер php

Tags: php

Есть онлайн чат на ajax, который реализован через long polling.

Хотел бы узнать как сервер вообще работает.

Например, у нас в чате ~50 пользователей онлайн, и с каждого пользователя на сервер отправляется запрос на сервер, как 1 скрипт обрабатывает (т.е. ждет новых сообщений в БД) для 50 клиентов?

Для каждого запроса выделяется отдельный поток?

Если есть у кого нибудь ссылки на подобную инфу - скиньте, буду благодарен.